# How to read XML in C# using Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSKUsPriceAndStockResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetSKUsPriceAndStockResult>
        <RequestStatus>
          <DateTime>2/28/2012 5:28:05 PM</DateTime>
          <Message>S200</Message>
        </RequestStatus>
        <SKUsDetails>
          <SKUDetails>
            <SKU>N82E16834230265</SKU>
            <Model>X54C-NS92</Model>
            <Stock>true</Stock>
            <Domain>newegg.com</Domain>
            <SalePrice>439.99</SalePrice>
            <ShippingCharge>0.00</ShippingCharge>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
          </SKUDetails>
        </SKUsDetails>
      </GetSKUsPriceAndStockResult>
    </GetSKUsPriceAndStockResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I read `<SKUDetails>` Node using XPath?. What will be XNamespace for above XML?

Comment: `<SKUDetails>` inside `<SKUsDetails>` seem a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)

**or**

**its better to use** [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) as your are using .net 4.0 and there is no need to learn XPath to traverse the xml tree.

Not sure about the xpath expression but you can code like this

```
string fileName = "data.xml";
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

// Compile a standard XPath expression
XPathExpression expr; 
expr = nav.Compile("/GetSKUsPriceAndStockResponse/GetSKUsPriceAndStockResult/SKUsDetails/SKUDetails");
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);
try
{
  while (iterator.MoveNext())
  {

  }
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: XPath is a useful (and industry standard thing).  Instead of going down a MS-specific rabbit hole, just load your xml into an XML Document (call it, say, doc), and do a XMLNode nodSKUDetails = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//SKUDetails");

Answer (score 3):

as **@Kirill Polishchuk** answered - `SKUDetails is defined in http://tempuri.org/`

he shows you how to get using `XDocument`

you can use alsow `XmlDocument` like this:

```
var dom = new XmlDocument();
dom.Load("data.xml");
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(dom.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://tempuri.org/");
var res = dom.SelectNodes("//a:SKUDetails", mgr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`SKUsDetails` is defined in `http://tempuri.org/` namespace. You can use this code to select `SKUsDetails` using XPath:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("1.xml");

var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.CreateReader().NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://tempuri.org/");

var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("//a:SKUsDetails", mgr);
```

To select `SKUDetails` use: `//a:SKUsDetails/a:SKUDetails`