# C# string manipulations to find all occurrences of a string within two specified strings

Tags: c#, string

I need to process the string shown here in a loop. The string would be any standard markup.
for eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
  <blog>
  <title> this is a title </title>
  <firstname>Karan</firstname>
  <lastname>Johar</lastname>
  </blog>
  <blog>
    <title> this is a title </title>
    <firstname>Karan</firstname>
    <lastname>Johar</lastname>
  </blog>
  <blog>
    <title> this is a title </title>
    <firstname>Karan</firstname>
    <lastname>Johar</lastname>
  </blog>
</article>
```

What I need to do is to get every occurrence of the content between `<title> ...</title>`
and then serially pass them into another function as and when they come.

Could anyone please guide?

Comment: Do you know xpath? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read XML in C# using Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511608/how-to-read-xml-in-c-sharp-using-xpath)

Comment: No XPath cant be used...as this isnt really guaranteed to be a valid xml markup ...string manipulation is the only avenue.

Comment: This not just a "string". This is an XML document. Parse it, e.g. with Linq to XML in the System.Xml.Linq namespace, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx

Comment: @Kris, i believe that can only work if the markup is valid..correct me if am wrong In my case the input files though xml are rarely valid ,so the possibilities of using xml methods go moot. I am sure we could use string manipulations instead.

Comment: Depending on how often the string is valid XML, I would follow a two step process. Try parsing as XML first and work with that. If parsing as XML fails, use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Option1:

If you are sure that the input file will have new lines, then you can try reading the content line by line and check if your string exists in that line, then pass that line to your

Comment: No thats not guaranteed that they will all be in new lines

Comment: Ok, what exactly you want to send to your another method.

Comment: pls see above comments

Answer (score 0):

As you told you have a string and assuming you want to read all titles and pass them into another function as a List   or serial

```
List<titles> titlesList=new List<string>();
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(XmlDocument, "<title>(?<data>.*?)<.title>");
foreach (Match x in collection)
{
    string text=x.Group["data"].Value;
    Func(text);
    titlesList.add(text);
}

Func(titlesList);
```

Comment: Why did you move the Func() call into the loop? It should have stayed after the loop. Alternatively, don't use a list at all, and call the func for each individual match.

Comment: Also, I would change the regular expression as such: `<title>(?<data>^<*?)</title>` (not tested). Meaning: stop the match at first '<' and require the / in the closing tag.

Comment: @Kris , i think he is correct when he moved it inside...elaborating on the requirement...i need to write the input string onto a pdf, so the function that i would write above would be for formatting title sections , the rest would be plain text. So the reason i had mentioned string manipulation earlier was i need to print the out put as the title tag content has the formatting , the rest no formatting... i mean both of the writes have to be done in sequence...i cant take a collection and do the formatting later

Comment: @user3218288 In an earlier version of this answer, he had a func in the loop which took the entire list as a parameter, not an individual match. That was wrong, but it has since been corrected.

Comment: @Kris oh ok , then i stand corrected :), so far i have 50% of the solution

Comment: There is another problem with this approach: the inner text may contain XML escapes, such as `&amp;`, comments, or whatever. I insist on trying to use an XML parser, if not on the entire document, than at least on the `<title>blahblahblah</title>` line.

Comment: yes it will not deal with XML escapes and replacing will be not a very good solution but it will work.

Comment: Sorry for responding late. But for using xpath you will have to use Xdocument.load(xmldoc). For this to work , we need a well formed xml.