# Extracting The particular atribute value using other attribute value in c#

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

Suppose I have the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Tasks>
    <Task>
         <id>1234</id>
         <name>abc</name>
    </Task>

    <Task>
         <id>5678</id>
         <name>xyz</name>
    </Task>
<Tasks>
```

How can I extract the value of `id` using the value of `name`? For example I know the name is `abc`. How can i extract the value `1234` from the above file?

Comment: [You should use XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511608/how-to-read-xml-in-c-sharp-using-xpath).

Comment: In xpath i can able to search only for eg in the above code <Task> tag contain some attribute and value like this.. <Task number = "125"> but the inner tag <Task> in plain one , is there any workaround??

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath to select element based on childs child value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683054/xpath-to-select-element-based-on-childs-child-value)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following XPath query to get the `id` element for a `Task` with the `name` of `abc`:

```
/Tasks/Task[name='abc']/id
```

Example of this is [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ce79f3c94f192de0f2423b5ce1c3c3d8).

Comment: Thank you so much Phylogenesis, is there any way i can do this using linq,my team want me to use linq:( ?? looking for your help

Comment: Thank you so much again, it worked for me:) one more query , is it possible to write the xml file without deleting its contents in linq??? hope our xml masters help in this regard