# How to get XmlElement from XmlNodeList in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Below is sample of my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<summary>  
  <testresult>    
    <result value="10" name="long">100</result>
    <result value="12" name="short">200</result>
    <result value="14" name="long">300</result>
  </testresult>
  <testresult>   
    <result value="10" name="short">50</result>
    <result value="12" name="short">60</result>
    <result value="14" name="long">70</result>
  </testresult>
</summary>
```

I need to get attribute values for result elements.

I done it using foreach loop as below.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(item.Value);
XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//testresult");

for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (XmlElement child in nodelist[i])
    {
        if (child.HasAttributes)
        {
            result.Add(child.Attributes["value"].Value); //This is working fine.
        }       
    }
}
```

**My ultimate goal is to identify the name and get value if name = "long" only.**

for that I need to get the value of **name Attribute**.
I need to do that **without using foreach loop**. Any suggestion to achieve my task **inside the for loop** ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use `XmlDocument` or you can use LINQ to XML?

Comment: Have you tried using XPath? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511608/how-to-read-xml-in-c-sharp-using-xpath

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel with XPath you will not be able to select attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your xml easy with XDocument:

```
var xDoc  = XDocument.Load(@"YourXmlFile");
var result = xDoc.Descendants("result")
              .Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value=="long")    
              .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ to XML then you even can get results as integers

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(item.Value);

var results = from r in xdoc.Descendants("result")
              where (string)r.Attribute("name") == "long"
              select (int)r.Attribute("value");
```

Output:

```
[10, 14, 14]
```

---

If you have to use XmlDocument

```
var result = from XmlElement tr in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//testresult")
             from XmlElement r in tr
             where r.Attributes["name"].Value == "long"
             select r.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

You can also provide more preciese XPath

```
var result = from XmlElement r in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//testresult/result[@name='long']")
             select r.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq to get all the values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("testresult").Select(x => new {
                result = x.Elements("result").Select(y => new {
                    value = (int)y.Attribute("value"),
                    name = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                    text = (int)y
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```